# How do I remove rain streaks form a rainy image

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am working under a professor, and I recently studied Conv-neural-networks and Generative adversarial Networks and was able to implement basic python codes on these topics using the MNIST dataset.
Now I am given an assignment to try and remove rain streaks from rainy images.
I read a paper where they used Auto-encoders and GAN's to do that, but I don't know what to do and how to proceed. I have 1000 clean images and 14000 rainy images 14 of each clean ones. I got this dataset from github and I also have some images of only rain streaks.I am fairly new to CNN's and GAN's and I don't even know if this is an easy task or a complex one just for me. But I am very confused.
Can anyone suggest some things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem using image to image translation methods.

- If you have paired images (clean image, and the corresponding rainy image), you can use some paired approaches like Pix2Pix (paper + github: [link](https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/)). The github implementation is easy to adapt to you case, just put your images in the corresponding folders, and lunch the training.
- If you don't have paired images, but images in the two domains (clear images, and rainy images), use an unsupervised image to image translation. CycleGan is a good architecture and it works very well ([link](https://junyanz.github.io/CycleGAN/)). The implementation is easy to use also.

NB: In all the cases, you will need a GPU for training the models!